liquibase loadData csv с вычисляемыми значениями
Мне нужно загрузить много данных из csv файла при помощи liquibase. Как это сделать я знаю, но есть нюанс, с которым непонятно что делать: некоторые поля вычисляемые, т.е. данные в них нужно загружать на основе вычилсения (select id from another_table where key = 'SOME_KEY').
Подскажите, можно ли как-то это сделать при помощи liquibase.loadData? Например, как-то, внедрить 'select id from t where key = ''' в csv?
